# Run multiple screens and attach them for a split view

Tags: linux, ssh, scripting, gnu-screen, window

So I'm new to screen and I've been using this .screenrc for now - https://gitlab.com/joaopizani/env.screenrc-ftw.

I'm trying to make a script that, given a target host, will do the following:

1. Open a screen, ssh to the target host
2. Open another screen, ssh to the target host, run htop
3. Attach both screens together for a split view

I've been able to do the first 2 by using `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`, followed by (assuming `HOST` is a given argument):

1. `ssh -dmS "terminal_HOST" ssh HOST`
2. `ssh -dmS "htop_HOST" ssh -t HOST htop`

I'm not able to attach the htop to the terminal (I don't mind doing the split with my predefined key-combo...)

Is this even possible?

Comment: This would arguably be easier to do from `tmux`. Would you care for a `tmux` solution, or is that not interesting?

Comment: Id rather stick with `screen` due to it's widespread distribution :)